# Google Sign-In for iOS: error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'"

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

'Cannot subscript a value of type `[String, AnyObject]` with an index of type String' for `options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]`. Swift 2, iOS 9.x, Google Sign in installed using CocoaPods. Any hints?

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options:     [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey], annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**function `before iOS 9.0`**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

**or with the method you are using, you can using it like (`Prior to iOS 9.0 and above`)**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
 -> Bool {
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                        annotation: [:])
}
```

**or to support both in `iOS 9 and above` and in `iOS 8.0 to iOS 9.0`**

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
 -> Bool {
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                        annotation: [:])
}

//for iOS 8, check availability   
@available(iOS, introduced=8.0, deprecated=9.0)
func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Comment: I am using both methods: application:openURL:options: and application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: which is deprecated according to Google Developer Guide. So I am not sure if I should accept this as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I found that I needed to use this version recently (i.e., Swift 3.x).  I hope this helps others with a similar compilation error.

```
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(
    url as URL!,
    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue] as! String?,
    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation.rawValue])
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 compatible answer by `El Captain v2.0`:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])
}

//for iOS 8, check availability
@available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 9.0)
func application(_ application: UIApplication,open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Comment: in the second method change the URL! to URL?