# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' google login frameworks

Tags: swift3, ios10, google-signin

I am using google login frameworks as per the document

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url as URL!,
                                                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                                                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

It is giving error

> `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'`

Request help regarding this.

Comment: Copy and paste the full error or screenshot from xcode if possible.

Comment: https://www.mx7.com/view2/zzYR2qvvDoTTyMY1 my screenshots

Comment: Upload images here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: [screenshot](https://www.mx7.com/i/dd7/rYhPEF.png) edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for `iOS 9.0` and prior, you should use this method .. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35594731/4601170)

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])-> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                        annotation: [:])
   }
```